# Handling WPF TabItems Visibility property

Tags: c#, wpf, visibility, tabitem

I have been reading about `Visibility.Collapsed` for `TabItems`. When the `Visibility` is set to `Collapsed`, the `TabItem` header is hidden but the contents are still visible.

I have also tried the following approch mentioned in [here](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/06/finding-elements-in-wpf-tree-both-ways), but no luck.

Is there any way to get the contents inside the `TabItems` to hide and also select the tab that is visible.

Comment: You don't need any of that. Conceptually, a `TabControl` is just a graphical representation of an `ObservableCollection<ViewModel>`, where each viewmodel is represented by a tab item, and there's only 1 `SelectedItem` at a given time.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need any of that. Conceptually, a `TabControl` is just a graphical representation of an `ObservableCollection<ViewModel>`, where each viewmodel is represented by a tab item, and there's only 1 `SelectedItem` at a given time:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window12"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window12" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using BaseFramework.MVVM;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class Window12 : Window
    {
        public Window12()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new TabbedViewModel()
                          {
                              Items =
                                  {
                                      new TabViewModel() {Title = "Tab #1", IsEnabled = true, IsVisible = true},
                                      new TabViewModel() {Title = "Tab #2", IsEnabled = false, IsVisible = true},
                                      new TabViewModel() {Title = "Tab #3", IsEnabled = true, IsVisible = false},
                                  }
                          };
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class TabbedViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> _items;
        public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Items
        {
            get { return _items ?? (_items = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>()); }
        }

        private ViewModelBase _selectedItem;
        public ViewModelBase SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange(() => SelectedItem);
            }
        }
    }

    public class TabViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange(() => Title);
            }
        }

        private bool _isEnabled;
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return _isEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange(() => IsEnabled);
            }
        }

        private bool _isVisible;
        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get { return _isVisible; }
            set
            {
                _isVisible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange(() => IsVisible);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, its just a matter of inheriting `TabViewModel` for each one of your tabs (creating the appropiate logic inside of each), and a proper `DataTemplate` for each one of these derived classes in the `app.xaml` or something.

Whenever you want to remove a tab item from the view, instead of manipulating the view you manipulate the ViewModel. this is the WPF approach for everything. It simplifies everything by removing the need to manipulate complex objects (UI elements) in code. Whenever you set

`TabbedViewModel.SelectedItem.IsVisible = false;`, make sure you also do:

`TabbedViewModel.SelectedItem = TabbedViewModel.Items.First(x => x.IsVisible && x.IsEnabled);`

This will prevent you from ever falling into the case of having an invisible tab item as the selected item.

Comment: Thank you. I shall work on this and update. The code seems to what I am looking for.

Comment: Is this still the prefered design patern in 2023?

Comment: @UriLondon yes. With the exception that **instead of WPF you should be using Avalonia**, and instead of manually implementing INPC for properties you should be using source-generated INPC properties, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Hi just Add and Remove the TabItems from TabControl instead of setting Visibility. There is one more issue with Turning on and off the Visibility and it is exception like Out of index when you scroll or minimize or resize the TabControl.